# MYSQL select based on the selects

Tags: mysql

You're help would be much appreciated...
If I have the following table and sample data... myGroupTable

group_Id : user_Id

    1 : 3

    1 : 7

    1 : 100

    2 : 3

    2 : 7

    2 : 100

    2 : 104

    4 : 42

    4 : 98

    4 : 13

I would like a sql statement that would... 
Return a group_Id that has exactly the specified user_Id's in them.
eg... is there a group_Id that has User_Id's 3, 7 and 100
answer: group_id 1.
Please note that I dont want it to return a group_Id 2, as that also has a user_Id of 104 in it...
Kind regards J

Comment: What did you tried? what doesn't work?

Comment: I really just need to be pointed in the right direction... using IN doesn't work, because using my example above... group_Id 2 would also get selected, beacause those values are in group_id 2... but I only want it to be selected if they are all in that group and no more.

Comment: Thanks ajreal, but that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative:

```
SELECT group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id) AS user_id_list
FROM group_user
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING user_id_list = '3,7,100'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... Is this going to run very slowly if you have a large database... or is this the best solution?... kind regards J

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    group_Id,
    SUM(
        IF user_Id = 3 THEN 1
        ELSEIF user_Id = 7 THEN 2
        ELSEIF user_Id = 100 THEN 4
        ELSE 8
    ) AS bits
FROM myGroupTable
GROUP BY group_Id
HAVING bits=7
```

This assumes that you cannot have duplicate user_Ids for the same group_Id, eg this could never happens:

```
group     user
   1         3
   1         3
```

**Edit:** You can build your query in the following way:

```
<?php
$ids = array(3, 7, 100);
$power = 2;
$query = "
    SELECT
    group_Id,
    SUM(
        IF user_Id = " .$ids[0]. " THEN 1 ";
foreach ($id in $ids) { 
    $query .= " ELSEIF user_Id = $id THEN " . $power;
    $power = $power * 2;
}
$query .= " ELSE $power
    ) AS bits
    FROM myGroupTable
    GROUP BY group_Id
    HAVING bits = " . ($power - 1);
```

Comment: Clever approach.  Should be noted that the "1", "2", and "4" used here are NOT related to the groups 1, 2, 4 in the question, but are in fact powers of 2.  You would build this query on demand with the members, and if there were 4 members required, the next would be "8", then "16", etc.

Comment: Yes, note that 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. are powers of two, and the final else must be an additional power of two.

Comment: The final bits=X is the sum of all the powers of two except the one in the ELSE field

Comment: What about the case when the user does have to put on different values for comparison? He has just given an example.

Comment: @Robert Martin Thanks Robert Martin.

Comment: @jon you're welcome. If you find this to be the correct answer, you are welcome to mark it as such

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

SELECT group FROM tbl WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM tbl WHERE user_id NOT IN(3,7,100)) AND user_id IN (3,7,100);

Answer (score -1):

```
select group_id,
sum(
  case user_id in(3,7,100)
  when 1 then 1
  else -99
  end
) as must_be_3
from group_user
group by group_id
having must_be_3=3;
```

Comment: That would match group_id 2, which the OP does not want.

Comment: Thanks for that @Bill ... with regard to which is better... is this going to be a faster select than the example you posted above with the GROUP_CONCAT ?.. Kind regards J

Comment: I can't predict that, because it depends on size of database, the server you run it on, presence of indexes, etc.